# LaTeX Editor with camelcase navigation

Tags: xetex, texlive, texstudio, editors

Is there are LaTeX editor which supports camelcase navigation. Jetbrains Webstorm allows camelcase navigation such that a `longCamelCaseWrittenWord` could be navigated in several steps.

Is such a thing available for any LaTeX/xelatex editors? Or any editor for that matter.

I currently use **texstudio** with **texlive**

**Edit**:

This question is not a duplicate, none of the answers mention anything about navigating through camelcase words.

**EDIT**:

To elaborate on the problem further... It will go like follows (underscore `_` represents the actual cursor position):

```
_LongCamelCaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
Long_CamelCaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamel_CaseWrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCase_WrittenWord -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCaseWritten_Word -> CTRL+RIGHT_ARROW ->
LongCamelCaseWrittenWord_
```

If `longCamelCaseWrittenWord` is one word, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and tapping <kbd>→</kbd> key does not take the cursor to the end of the word; rather, it takes the cursor through, one word at a time.

Hope I make sense.

Comment: The reason I've duped is that 'which editor is best', even if it comes down to esoteric features, is basically a 'shopping list' (there is no one answer, and it's not some _expertise in TeX_ helps with): we have the one big list to allow comparison, and additional data can be added there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you are looking for a Wiki-capable LaTeX editor.

The only remotely near that I know is [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/), but is not a LaTeX editor but a  notebook where the pages are stored as .txt files (not .tex) with a wiki markup fromat, that however you can export easily to LaTeX (or HTML, or markdown, or RST). You can export single pages or  whole notebook.

The drawback:  Zim is a wiki-like personal notebook application, not a full word processor, and the format is perforce simple. Even adding some extensions, you will have six levels of headers, numbered and non-numbered list, camelcase links (`\href` when exported to LaTeX), images and tables (without floats), bold and italic font, and litte more ... but could be a good first-step to organize contents of a  complex project in several LaTeX subdocuments and at certain point export and carry on with a true LaTeX editor for the final format.

**Edit**

For vim users there also [SoyWiki](http://danielchoi.com/software/soywiki.html) that do not force any text markup (you can edit just LaTeX code directly) but you cannot use filename extensions (as .tex) in wiki directories, and you cannot make auxiliary files in the wiki subdirectories. A MWE on your `/project` directory could be a `foo/FooWiki` file like that:

```
%  foo.FooWiki
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a \LaTeX\ document. 
It does nothing when compiled
\end{document}
Go to main.HomePage
Go to foo.OtherDocument
```

In a terminal this is the look and feel:

[image: mwe]

The page link the page `HomePage` in the /project/main´ subdirectory (both are automatically created the first time that you run `soywiki`, and AFAIK you cannot change this behavior) and `/project/foo/OtherDocument` (if that subdirectory/file does not exist, just <kbd>Enter</kbd> over the link  will do the job).

Note that there are also unexpected link to `foo/LaTeX` but as `soywiki` do not modify that code in any sense, "`FooWiki`" can be compiled without problems in spite that there are a link inside the document environment thas is really a control sequence.

However, as far I know, `soywiki` cannot deal with generated files (.pdf, .aux, etc.) in wiki subdirectories so you ***must*** compile files like `FooWiki` outside of the `/project/foo` (in `/project`, for instance). I find this a bit annoying for previews but for a vim user maybe is not a major drawback using hard links, compiler options or some script.

Note: Sorry if I describe a clumsy use of the tool, I discovered it only a couple of hours ago, and I normally do not use vim (nor emacs).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. I really appreciate your taking the time out. I have included some edits in the question. Could you please go through them?

Comment: @manucpp Sorry, by "camelcase navigation" I understood convert automatically convert WikiWords in links to different files (I hope that the answer is still useful for people finding this question with the same thoughts).  I do not know any  editor where `Ctrl`+`-->` select word by word  instead of the whole wikiWord, that is actually a very standard behavior in text editors. Maybe soft hyphens (`\-`) help in this case? This will break Wiki\-Words in the editor but in the PDF the hyphen is only show if a line break is really needed.

Comment: Jetbrains Webstorm has the feature of navigating through words within camelcase words. That is one editor I know. I thought other editors may have a feature or a plugin for the same.

Comment: @manucpp Well, as gigiair briefly said,  also   [Emacs have a CamelCase mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CamelCase) but Emacs is not (only) an editor, and I've never had enough brain, fingers and time to learn how to use it.  To avoid a flame war, of course, we also to mention that seem that  [vim also have a plugin for that](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words). But as I said, I use vim only occasionally (I hate the dual mode of vim) and not the right person to help with vim or emacs magics.

Comment: @manucpp There are a plugin [Case Conversion plugin for Sublime](https://github.com/jdavisclark/CaseConversion) that allow convert to/from camelCase, but as far I can see, do not allow jump to each subword in a camelcase string.

Answer (score -1):

emacs subword-mode do it. M-x subword-mode.

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer.

Comment: When subword-mode is active (M-x subword-mode), you can proceed camelcase navigation with M-f or M-b. (Hold the Meta key (Alt key) and strike f or b (forward or backward).

Comment: for more information, M-x describe-minor-mode RET subword RET